# iPhone sdk: how to solve this warnings

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hi i am working with Twitter, in this there will be two class, for showing tweet in table

view and retrieving string for table view like user photos, screen name, username and date

one class is MyTweetViewController.h //I am importing the Tweet class also

and next one is Tweet.h class

```
//this line i am getting warning i.e NO initWithTweetDictionary method not found,

Tweet *tweet =[[Tweet alloc] initWithTweetDictionary:tweetDict];



- -(void)statusesReceived:(NSArray *)statuses forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier 

// this is delegate for MGTwitter for retrieving information of user

{
    NSLog(@"Statuses Receives: %@",statuses);

       {
        tweetArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for(NSDictionary *tweetDict in statuses) 

        {

Tweet *tweet =[[Tweet alloc] initWithTweetDictionary:tweetDict];// here i am getting 

warring  i.e NO initWithTweetDictionary method not found, 

            [tweetArray addObject:tweet];

            [tweet release];

        }
    }


    [self.tweetsTableView reloadData];
}


////Tweet.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface Tweet : NSObject {

    NSDictionary *contentsTweet;

}

-(NSString*)userName;

-(NSString*)tweet;

-(NSString*)image_url;

-(NSString*)created_at;



@end

///Tweet.m

#import "Tweet.h"


@implementation Tweet

-(id)initWithTweetDictionary:(NSDictionary*)_contentsTweet {

    if(self = [super init]) {

        contentsTweet = _contentsTweet;

        [contentsTweet retain];
    }

    return self;
}

-(NSString*)userName {

    NSDictionary * dic = (NSDictionary*)[contentsTweet objectForKey:@"user"];

    return [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
}

-(NSString*)tweet {

    return [contentsTweet objectForKey:@"text"];
}
-(NSString*)image_url {

    NSDictionary * dic = (NSDictionary*)[contentsTweet objectForKey:@"user"];

    return [dic objectForKey:@"profile_image_url"];

}

- (void)dealloc {

    [contentsTweet release];

    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Please suggest me

Thank you

Comment: Indent your code by four spaces and you won't have to double-space everything.

Comment: Please make an effort when writing your questions. Format code properly and, to the best of your ability, use correct spelling and grammar. Considering that you've already asked 25 questions, you should know this by now.

Comment: sorry i keep this in my mind for next time, i will follow yours suggestion and not repeat next time, thank you suggestions Jasarien and Marcelo Cantos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Tweet.h you have to declare `-(id)initWithTweetDictionary:(NSDictionary*)_contentsTweet;`
in order to make the warning dissappear.

```
@interface Tweet : NSObject {
    NSDictionary *contentsTweet;
}

-(id)initWithTweetDictionary:(NSDictionary*)_contentsTweet;
-(NSString*)userName;
-(NSString*)tweet;
-(NSString*)image_url;
-(NSString*)created_at;

@end
```

Comment: Thank you SorinA, This work for me, i think i am so poor in coding (objective C) how to improve, my coding skill and understanding of coding, suggest me

Comment: you can start by reading http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/ also you can try to read some of the books recomended here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35431/what-is-the-best-book-for-learning-objective-c